# Changing the directory in swtich case - shell script (windows)

Tags: bash, shell, switch-statement, git-bash

I am using windows 10 and gitbash to run the below script

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Select - 1 or 0"
while :
do
  read INPUT_STRING
  case $INPUT_STRING in
    1) cd /d/Workspace
       break
       ;;

    0) echo "Exit"
       break
       ;;

    *) echo "Please try again"
       ;;
  esac
done
echo 
echo "Bye!"
```

I wanted to move to a specified directory when I select option 1 but it seems `cd` option is not executed, not sure the reason. How can I make it work?

Also, the root directory is in c drive `/c/Users/username`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question, looks like the the expected behavior was to run the script, and change the working directory for the calling process.

The current working directory is specific to each process. When the script modifies the
current working directory, it only affect it own working directory. This will also impact any future process that will be started fro the running shell. It will NOT have impact on other processes in the system, which will continue use their current working directory.

For the specific case that your top level shell is git-bash, you can use `source script-name.sh` to execute the above script inside the parent process. Taking this approach will modify the current shell process working directory.

Comment: I put the alias to execute the script `alias repo='sh /d/Workspace/bash-script-workspace/talk.sh'` but in the end everthing executed but i didn't got swtiched to the directory. Can you help me out with an example ? also my parent directory is in c drive and how can i ru n a script wihich is in d drive from parent dir?

Comment: Consider using the 'source', as suggested in answer, instead of 'sh': `alias repo='source /d/Workspace/bash-script-workspace/talk.sh'`